# Crossfade Animation with multiple Images using Ffmpeg

Tags: android, image, video, ffmpeg, slideshow

I'm creating video with Multiple images using Ffmpeg and i'm using given link -

**(Remember most important thing is All the images have different sizes)**

https://superuser.com/a/834035/1243959

Now First of all i'm creating video with fade in/out animation and for that i'm using 3rd code with title `For input images with varying or arbitrary sizes` and it works well -

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input0.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input1.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input2.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input3.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i input4.png \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v0]; \
 [1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v1]; \
 [2:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v2]; \
 [3:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v3]; \
 [4:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1[v4]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

but when i want to create Cross Fade animation using given command with the title `MP4 output` in `Cross fade` section,in output video,portrait images are fits into video,but square and landscape images are getting cropped (@llogan has specified that if images have different sizes than we have to use same command which is used for fade in/out) -

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 3.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 4.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 5.png \
-filter_complex \
"[1]format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4/TB[f0]; \
 [2]format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+8/TB[f1]; \
 [3]format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+12/TB[f2]; \
 [4]format=yuva444p,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+16/TB[f3]; \
 [0][f0]overlay[bg1];[bg1][f1]overlay[bg2];[bg2][f2]overlay[bg3]; \
 [bg3][f3]overlay,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

But I don't know exactly what to do and I think I have to first fit the images in a certain ratio like `1280 * 720`, by which all the images will be of same size and then the animation should be applied to those images and may be different solution can work too but right now I'm confused about what to do because I've tried a lot of solutions like scaling images and some other attempts and not a single solution worked (maybe I didn't even try right)..

if `SAR` and `DAR` can help than they are as below
(I don't know difference between these variables):

```
SAR 1:1 / DAR 197:295
SAR 1:1 / DAR 2:3
SAR 96:96 / DAR 16:9
SAR 1:1 DAR / 540:961
SAR 1:1 DAR / 2567:3113
```

Any help will be appreciated..Thank you!

Comment: xfade, as shown in the answer by Баяр Гончикжапов, is now the better way to do this, but I have been too lazy to update that answer you linked to.

Comment: It's ohk,No problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variant 2, using fade+overlay:

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 3.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 4.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 5.png \-filter_complex "
[0]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4/TB[f0];
[1]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+8/TB[f1];
[2]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+12/TB[f2];
[3]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+16/TB[f3];
[4]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fade=d=1:t=in:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+20/TB[f4];
[f0][f1]overlay[bg1];
[bg1][f2]overlay[bg2];
[bg2][f3]overlay[bg3];
[bg3][f4]overlay,format=yuv420p[v]
" -map [v] -movflags +faststart -y out.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for answering and it worked out well,looks like `xfade` will also work,but for right now this solution also works well,Thank you!

Comment: is it the `scale` filter which makes operation too slow??

Comment: @VivekThummar , if pictures has same size, you can remove `scale,pad,setsar` filters or remove `scale` only.

Comment: Hey, i want to just ask you that have you ever feel any problem with camera images because sometimes, some of the camera image gets rotated automatically, i have faced same type of issue with camera videos also but not dealt with ffmpeg, just with UI, but here the case is to deal with ffmpeg,..what exactly i want to do is that if the image is from camera than apply it to slideshow but with rotation, is it possible to do this in same command?

Comment: ffmpeg can't understand rotated jpegs from camera. I didn't see any parameter for rotate with `ffprobe -show_format -show_streams -print_format ini -i 20210313_125143.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

[xfade](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade)

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 1.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 2.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 3.png \
-loop 1 -t 5 -i 4.png \
-filter_complex "
[0]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[0p];
[1]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[1p];
[2]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[2p];
[3]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[3p];
[0p][1p]xfade=duration=1:offset=4[1x];
[1x][2p]xfade=duration=1:offset=8[2x];
[2x][3p]xfade=duration=1:offset=12[3x]
" -map [3x] -c:v libx264 -crf 17 /tmp/output.mp4
```

generated by script:

```
#!/bin/bash
LST=($(ls -1 *.png))
TOT=${#LST[*]}
f="${LST[0]}"
INP=("-loop" "1" "-t" "5" "-i" "$f")
echo $f
FLS="[0]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1[0p]"
PDX="[0p]"
OFS=0
for (( i=1; i<=$(( $TOT -1 )); i++ )); do
  f="${LST[$i]}"
  INP+=("-loop" "1" "-t" "5" "-i" "$f")
  ((OFS += 4))

  PDS="[${i}p]"
  FLS+=";[${i}]scale=-2:720,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1${PDS}"
  FLX+=";${PDX}${PDS}xfade=duration=1:offset=${OFS}"
  PDX="[${i}x]"
  FLX+="${PDX}"

  echo $OFS $f
done

echo $FLS
echo ""
echo $FLX
echo ""
rm /tmp/output.mp4
ffmpeg "${INP[@]}" -filter_complex "$FLS $FLX" -map $PDX -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 20 -y /tmp/output.mp4 -hide_banner

ffplay -autoexit /tmp/output.mp4
```

[updated] code optimization

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg, in version 4.2.2LTS it's giving me error "No such filter: 'xfade'" and in version 4.4LTS error is No such filter:''

Comment: @VivekThummar FFmpeg 4.2 is too old for xfade. The `No such filter:` is probably due to a quoting error.