# Sequence of images of different dimensions to video FFMPEGCORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ffmpeg

This is my first time with [ffmpegcore](https://github.com/rosenbjerg/FFMpegCore). I'm trying to convert sequence of png images of different dimensions (height and width) to a video using ffmpegcore. I could create a video. The issue is the video frame is set to the dimension of the first image (eg 174 x 700) so when a higher dimension images (eg 500 x 700) follows, it is shrunk with in (174 x 700).

Could somebody help me resolve the issue?

I want my video with images of their actual dimensions.

```cs
FFMpeg.JoinImageSequence(videoName, frameRate: 15, imageInfos.ToArray());
```

`imageInfos` has images of different dimensions

Comment: have a look at this link, may be it will help you.. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65037720/10752962

Comment: How else would you expect it to behave? The video file MUST have  a single resolution. It cannot change resolution from frame to frame